# Is customizing the logo/theme allowed in jasper server?

Tags: licensing, jasperserver

I am  planning to use Jasper server. But its not decided whether i will go with community or proffesional version. 
See [Licensing](http://www.jaspersoft.com/editions)

I have few question about AGPL license(for JS community edition)  and Commercial license(for JS professional version)

As of now most of the requirements are fullfilled with community edition except that i want to change theme and logo of 
default jasper community edition. But i am not sure whether i am allowed to do this in which version(community or commercial
or both ) if required  as i am layman in this field ?

For information :- My product is similar to e-retailing product where users can purchase product online. I sell this product to different companies where company deploys it and then end users access the application. Reporting functionality will be used by company administrators not the end users.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question regarding licensing should be put to the licensor directly or to a qualified legal consultant.

Comment: Actually its a AGPL license for community version. so i thought any experts alreading using this kind of license can share his inputs

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do it with the commercial edition as it is extensively described in the documentation (using themes) and embedding jasper within your application is done using iFrames, visualize.js, and the REST_V2 webservices.

Check out the theme stuff in the documentation but essentially you can customize the css of the server as well as any images displayed.

See **JasperReports-Server-Admin-Guide**

https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation?version=13758